# Sandbox refreshed from another sandbox doesn't have active users

Tags: sandbox, refresh, invalid

I can't believe it happened but I did it...

Let's assume following scenario - we have Production org with user1@example.com (that's the only user I have access to on prod).

Then we have 2 developer sandboxes - S1 with user2@example.com and S2 with user2@example.com (note that these are the same users on both sandboxes).
Now I'm going to refresh S2 directly from S1 by clicking "Refresh" on prod with context of user1@example.com.

I tried to login to S2 using original username from before refresh - doesn't work.

I tried using production username with suffix of my refreshed sandbox - doesn't work.

After the refresh is done, it seems that S2 doesn't have ANY active users...
All of them are having '.invalid' suffix on their email addresses.

Anybody have any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried logging into S2 with username "user2@example.com" and password same as that in S1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose you are a Partner with access to Environment Hub? Cause that will allow you to SSO into the sandbox without an actual login flow.

Failing that, either:

1) Log a case to Salesforce to straighten it out.

or 2) Set up a user1@example.com user in S1, with a valid email and password you know, and then refresh S2 from S1 again.

or 3) Set up your network's IP address in S1 as a trusted IP, then refresh S2 from S1 again, and you should be able to get in without a verification code.

or 4) If you already know the security token for S1 user2@example.com, it should be the same in S2 so you may have various avenues to get into the sandbox, e.g. use Data Loader to change the email address to a valid one, or use the username/PW/token to secure a Session ID that you can use to get into the sandbox via frontdoor.jsp.

Comment: Second option worked for me! Discussed other options with my friends and seems that all of them are possible and working solutions. Thanks Charles for that!!

Answer (score 1):

Hope your user have system admin profile, When you refresh S2 sandbox from S1 sandbox, you can login using S1 sandbox credential just replace the suffix part of your username with S2 name. Once you logged in then you can change email address.

Hope it answer your question!!

Comment: This login accepts password but is sending verification code to invalid email address. So logging in is still impossible. And there was no SMS verification enabled before.

Answer (score 0):

If you clicked "refresh" on prod, are you sure you selected S1 to refresh from as it defaults to Prod and if you're quick you might forget to change it.

Either way, if you're stuck - whoever initiated the sandbox has a normal email. You should be able to reset that password at the very least and get an email to change your password.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333417&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

[image]

Comment: Sandbox cloning has been a feature for 2 years now.

Comment: I didn't say cloning doesn't exist. I'm trying to clarify what the user did.

Comment: The refresh feature includes the option to choose a source sandbox to clone from instead of Prod.

Comment: Ah, I see my wording and what you're saying. Yes, i'll edit that.